# Rails form_for selection box, show all records but store ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I have a software table, which has 4 fields; id, vendor, title and edition. I need a drop down box in my licenses form which will show every record like this: vendor - title - edition, but then only save the id of the chosen record to the database. I'm currently using a text box where the user can just enter the id of the software which will be saved to the database. here is my current form:

```
<%= form_for(@licenses) do |f| %>

<div class="well">
<%= f.label 'Software' %><br />
<%= f.text_field :software_id %>


<%= f.label 'Quantity' %><br />
<%= f.text_field :amount %>

<%= f.submit 'add'%>
</div>

<% end %>
```

I need to change the software text field into a drop down box, sorry if this is vague, i've not had anything to do with drop down boxes before.

Comment: You may find some help here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) for populating drop box

create a method in softwarer model like

```
def title_edition
"#{self.vendor.name}- #{self.title} - #{edition}"
end
@softwares = Software.all #In controller
```

and in view

```
<%= f.collection_select :software_id ,@softwares,:id,:title_edition %>
```

Comment: i get this error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)` on this line: `<%= f.collection_select @softwares,:id,:title_edition %>`

Comment: now i get `undefined method 'name' for "Microsoft SPLA":String`

Comment: you can remove .name from self.vendor.name

Answer (score 0):

You would want [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) with something like this:

```
f.collection_select(:software_id, Software.all, :id, :blah, :prompt => true)
```

Now the `:blah` is the tricky thing. In your `Software` model you will need to define a method that returns the concatenated string you would like; I called it `:blah` to draw your attention to it but it can be named anything. It would look like this:

```
def blah
    "#{self.vendor}-#{self.title}-#{self.edition}"
end
```

That should return the string like you mentioned and when you call it in `collection_select` display it like you want it.